# How do you remove the contents of a docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a volume created from a docker-compose.yml file. Let's call the volume my_volume and the container it's associated with my_container. I want to script the removal of the contents of the volume. All of the below assumes that my_container has been stopped, but not removed.

I can list the contents of the volume using:

```
docker run --rm -v my_volume:/data/ ubuntu ls -la /data
```

This works, so next I try to remove the contents of the data folder using:

```
docker run --rm -v my_volume:/data/ ubuntu rm -rf /data/*
```

No error message is reported so things appear successful, but when I list the contents of the volume again, none of the data in the volume has been removed.

I can accomplish the removal by entering a container and then doing the removal like so:

```
docker run --rm -it -v my_volume:/data/ ubuntu /bin/bash
```

then from within the container:

```
rm -rf /data/*
```

This works fine and the contents are removed, but this defeats the purpose since it's not scriptable. Any ideas why rm does not work when I try to use it outside of the container and how I might go about removing the contents of the volume successfully? I should note that I don't want to remove the volume and create a new one as doing so requires removing the original container/image associated with the volume which I don't want to do. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe not really where you're looking for but you're able to clear your volume with `rm -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data/*`

Comment: Other things I tried `docker run --rm -v my-volume:/data/ ubuntu rm -rf  data/` worked but gave a device is busy warning/error. Another 'solution' was removing everything seperatly (but you can only do this when you always know what your volume will contain: `docker run --rm -v my-volume:/data/ ubuntu rm -rf  data/dir1 data/dir2 data/file1 ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas why rm does not work when I try to use it outside of the container

I believe what is happening is that `/data/*` is being evaluated in the host shell. So the container is actually being run with the command `rm -rf /data/somefile /data/otherfile ...` with the list of files in the `/data` directory on the host. If those files don't match the container then it will appear to not have removed anything.

You can use single quotes to prevent the expansion from happening in the host shell.

```
rm -rf '/data/*'
```

Comment: Docker seems to pass any quoting into the container, or else it's running it without a shell to expand, so you'll get a `/data/*` not found. You can call a shell to do the expansion for you: `docker run --rm -v my_volume:/data/ ubuntu /bin/sh -c "rm -rf /data/*"`