# How to delete a file from docker container volume with python programmatically?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

Our project has a docker-compose.yml file. There is a volume for our containers. I can add a .zip file to this volume for a test process. And then I can extract the zip file to the subfolder of the volume folder. But I have to delete unnecessary files and folders from the subfolder. I need just HTML files for this test. For this reason, I have to remove the files and directories. I use the "os.remove" method for files and "shutil.rmtree" method for non-empty directories. However, There is no any changing the in the subfolder. These uncessary files and directories don't delete from docker container volumes. Could you help me about that?

```
PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER = "/app_testing_data/pre_release_test_folder/"

     for file_name in folder_list_array:
        if ensure_file_extension(file_name,"html") == False:
            if "." in file_name:                    
                try:
                    os.remove(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                    logger.logCritical("os.remove -> file_name -> " +Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                    #os.unlink(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.logError("os.remove:"+str(e))
            else:
                try:
                    shutil.rmtree(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                    logger.logCritical("shutil.rmtree -> file_name -> " +Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.logError("shutil.rmtree:"+str(e))

            folder_list_array.remove(file_name)
```

My for loop logic looks good. I don't take any errors.

[image]

And Then, I check my container with the "exec -it bash" command. There is no any changing.
I need to delete files except for html files.

[image]

Edit for comment:

Firstly, I uploaded a .zip file and saved it. :

```
if ensure_file_extension(uploaded_zip.filename, "zip"):
                logger.logDebug("uploaded result : "+ str(ensure_file_extension(uploaded_zip.filename, "zip")))

                uploaded_zip_filename = uploaded_zip.filename
                ensure_dir_exists("/app_testing_data")

                # Directory
                directory = "pre_release_test_folder"
                # Parent Directory path
                parent_dir = "/app_testing_data"

                path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)

                try:
                    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
                    logger.logDebug("Directory '%s' created successfully" % directory)
                except OSError as error:
                    logger.logDebug("Directory '%s' can not be created" % directory)    

                zip_save_path = os.path.join(path, uploaded_zip_filename)
                uploaded_zip.save(zip_save_path)
```

And then I extracted this .zip file :

```
 zip_file_path = Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER + self.targetKitName # self.targetKitName this is actually zip file name.

    with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zipObj:# Extract all the contents of zip file in current directory
        zipObj.extractall(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER)
```

I can extract successfully. You can see this from the above second image for docker container exec.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to show the full function you're having problems with? at the moment you have one folder `PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER ` constant which you are constructing the file path from, but you are searching for files in `folder_list_array` so you may not be creating a valid path. I would recommend you use `os.path.join` for concatenating paths rather than using `+`. You could also use `os.path.isfile` to check if file exists rather than checking if there is a `.` in the name.

Comment: If os.remove calls the shell command rm in the brackground, then you are maybe a victim of the problem described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415804/how-do-you-remove-the-contents-of-a-docker-volume). Try putting single quotes around the string the defines the path. Something like  " ' blabla ' "

Comment: @Jhon Doe    I have tried your advice. But I take  this error: os.remove:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'/app_testing_data/pre_release_test_folder/en-us_image_0000001052276089.png'"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code to something like the following (using `rm -rf` instead of `os.remove`, since we already know how to solve it with `rm -rf` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415804/how-do-you-remove-the-contents-of-a-docker-volume) answer):

```
import subprocess

PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER = "/app_testing_data/pre_release_test_folder/"

     for file_name in folder_list_array:
        if ensure_file_extension(file_name,"html") == False:
            if "." in file_name:                    
                try:
                    subprocess.run(["rm", f"'{Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name}'"])
                    logger.logCritical("os.remove -> file_name -> " +Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                    #os.unlink(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.logError("os.remove:"+str(e))
            else:
                try:
                    shutil.rmtree(Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                    logger.logCritical("shutil.rmtree -> file_name -> " +Constant.PRE_RELEASE_ZIP_FILE_FOLDER+file_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.logError("shutil.rmtree:"+str(e))

            folder_list_array.remove(file_name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This doesn't work for me. :/

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce now (I'm on mobile phone). What error did you get ?

Comment: I didn't get any errors.  .s

Comment: Can you try again with my edited code ? (without the -rf flag)

Comment: rm command needs to  any flag. It gives an error like that: rm --help .....

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile and the way you are running the container to your question, please ? I tried to create a minimum reproducible example here and I can remove the volume file from inside the container with os.remove (without any modification to what you are doing originally). It also removed the file from the host, as expected

Comment: i suspect that your problem may be the path that you are searching inside the container

Comment: It is very weird. I don't understand that. Actually, I have checked the paths with isfile method. It returns true. However, the remove method don't work correctly.

Comment: Let's first eliminate the possibility of it being a OS issue. I suggest you to try the following: Take a Dockerfile starting from python:3.9 with WORKDIR set to /test and a line "CMD sleep infinity" at the end. In your host, create a folder /test and put an empty file inside it. Then, build the image with "docker build -t test ." and run the container with "docker run --name=test --volume=/test:/test  test". Go inside the container, launch interactive python and remove the file from /test folder with os.remove. Verify that the file is removed from both, the container and the host